# Heroku installing app sushi , push db to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to upload my db dump file to Heroku to manage the website. It's a static file. When I follow the instruction given in Heroku site, I got errors. I might get it wrong so want to be clarified by many experts. Please help me!

What is the app sushi? I kept trying to push my db dump file to Heroku server. All configuration is set.

This is a command I put.

```
$heroku pg:push outfile HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE --app sushi
```

This is a result I got.

```
You do not have permission to view resources for sushi.
You need to have the deploy privilege on this app.
```

When I command

```
$heroku config
```

AWS, DATAbase URL, Bucket name etc are well set. Many commands I see from this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql and none of them worked to me because I don't have a permission to app sushi. How can I get the permission?

Comment: `sushi` is just the example app name.  Replace `sushi` with the actual name of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I now moved to the next step!

Comment: I don't know why I need to come here to figure this detail. So far, not impressed with the intuitiveness of the heroku documentation.

Answer (score 2):

sushi is just the example app name given for reference , please replace sushi with the actual name of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is confusing. Like "infused" commented, "sushi" is an example app name, you should replace that with the app name you have.

If your app name is "apidata", then you should write:

```
$heroku pg:push outfile HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE --app apidata
```

You can find your app name in the app menu and in the url like this:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/apidata
being "apidata" your app name.

Kind of late, but might help future doubts since this tutorial is still this confusing.